# Is it possible to use "%{HTTP_HOST}" in ProxyPass?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2, mod-proxy, proxypass

I'm trying to implement a transparent proxy using apache2 and mod_proxy that for now - doesn't do anything. just forwards the traffic to the correct "host".

I don't want it to be host-dependant - but dynamic so it'll work for all hosts.
I tried to do this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteLogLevel 5
RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1
ProxyPass / http://$1
```

I also tried several other approaches (none worked).
Is there any way I can access the "host" from the header and use it in the ProxyPass directive?

In nginx I would use $host, $remote_addr, etc.. any way to replace that on apache?

What I need is to be able to access %{HTTP_HOST}, %{REQUEST_URI} and %{SERVER_PORT} inside the ProxyPass command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just answering my own question:

I was missing 2 things:

the configuration should be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [P]
```

Not to forget to enable inherit in the virtual directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

Answer (score 4):

To use Apache ProxyPass directives with dynamic hostnames you will need to also use ModRewrite.

## Objective

All requests to the virtualhost will ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse (also known as an "Apache Gateway") to the %{HTTP_HOST}

The only reason this would make sense to do is if you have localhost entries on the apache server for specfic host names

## Examples

### Localhost File

```
10.0.0.2 foo.bar.com    
10.0.0.3 bar.bar.com
```

### How it works

1. The client makes a request to foo.bar.com (dnslookup is a public IP... YOUR APACHE SERVER)
2. Your apache server has a localhost entry of 10.0.0.2 for foo.bar.com (some other server on your network)
3. The request goes through ModRewrite and /path1 is appended, then handed off to ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse
4. ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse hand the call off to foo.bar.com at ip 10.0.0.2

Client requests foo.bar.com ---reverse proxies to----> foo.bar.com/path1 (on some OTHER internal server)

## Apache Configuration

```
    <VirtualHost *:443>
    Servername *

    # Must not contain /path1 in path (will add /path1)
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path1/.*
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/path1$1 [NC,R=302,L]

    # Must contain /path1 in path (will send request to the proxy)
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteOptions Inherit
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/path1/.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [NC,P]

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyRequests Off

    ProxyPass            /  https://$1/
    ProxyPassReverse     /  https://$1/

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ###################
    # SSL Constraints #
    ###################

    SSLProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 +TLSv1

    # Choose cipher suites
    SSLHonorCipherOrder On
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!SSLv2:!EXPORT

    # SameOrigin The page can only be displayed in a frame on the same origin as the page itself
    Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN

    SSLCertificateFile     /etc/apache2/example.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/apache2/example.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/gd_bundle.crt
    SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read this page if you haven't done it already :

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#forwardreverse

I think the ProxyRequests directive is what you are looking for.